# How to change the Google Cloud Composer environments's service account after the environment has been created?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, google-iam

We have a cloud composer instance set up with the default compute engine service account as the environment's service account ([set up by default](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/access-control#service-account)). We have created a new service account to use instead in the cloud composer instance but we can't find an option to change the environment's service account in the Environment Configuration page. Other fields have "Edit" options at the end of their rows but we can't find the option to edit the service account field.

[image: service account with no option to edit it]

I found an [old Google Group conversation from 2018](https://groups.google.com/g/cloud-composer-discuss/c/wG6gZeM_Xo0) that said it's technically possible by creating a new node pool in GKE but this isn't recommended due to the likelihood that it will break the environment.

**How do we swap out the old, default compute engine service account to our new service account?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud Composer 2](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/access-control) uses two types of IAM service accounts:

- Cloud Composer Service Agent account
- Environment's service account

Normally the Cloud Composer default SA can't be changed in the configuration and it will be used to create the Composer instances and machines.

But you can set the environment's service account. This account will be used at runtime with `Airflow` scheduler and workers, to allows access to `GCP` resources from DAGs.

**Unfortunately if you created a `Composer` instance with an environment's service account, you can't change it after.**

If you need to change this SA, you have to destroy and recreate the `Composer` Cluster with this new Service Account.

If you have a tool like `Terraform`, it's easier to automate this process and recreate the Cluster with your configuration.

In the case of Composer cluster recreation, you can copy all your DAG folders from the previous bucket to the new with `gsutil`.

Comment: Ah yes I mean the environment's service account, will edit question to specify. How do you change the environment's service account at runtime?

Comment: Ok I edited my answer to give you more info. Unfortunately you can't change this SA at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's impossible to change Service Account for running Cloud Composer. I'd setup new environment and just copy DAGs from the old bucket to the new one. And you can test your code with new service account (if you have sufficient permissions).

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it looks like we'll have to do this